# Finding missing date ranges between different intervals SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

-- Input

```
CREATE TABLE #DATES( StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME ) 

INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ( '2014-09-01 00:00:00.000','2015-09-02 23:59:59.000')

INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ( '2014-01-16 00:00:00.000','2014-04-04 23:59:59.000')

INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ( '2012-09-04 00:00:00.000','2014-01-15 23:59:59.000')

INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES ( '2011-09-05 00:00:00.000','2012-09-03 23:59:59.000')
```

Output

```
|-----------StartDate-----------|-----------EndDate -----------|

| 2014-04-05 00:00:00.000 | 2014-08-31 23:59:59.000 |
```

There can also be multiple gaps and can also be grouped for a single entity.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing much trying to find a way to do it. Thinking of adding 1 day to EndDate and substracting 1 sec from StartDate and compare dates.

Comment: What you need to do is group islands of continuous dates. Jeff Moden has a great article that explains how to do this quite easily at sql server central. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: The grouping is already done in the data, What i need is after the grouping find full date range that is missing. I went through the article but didnt help.

Comment: No...the grouping is not done in your data. You have multiple rows in your sample that make up your date range. And there is no chance you read that article to understand what it or I was trying to tell you in 3 minutes.

Comment: I already read the article before posting this question.

Comment: Well then perhaps you can try to explain your requirements a bit more clearly? I understand the multiple gaps but what does "can also be grouped for a single entity" mean?

Comment: By Single Entity means like a Person. Lets say a person have bank transactions from January to March then there are missing transactions from April to June and then again transactions exists from July to December. In this case the output that i need is the missing date range is 1st April to 30th June. I have tried to explain in simple words let me know if you need any more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the Solution. Not really proud of the solution. also in the end i will also require the overlap check between dates. But for now it resolves the blockade

```
SELECT StartFrom.StartDate, B.EndDate FROM 
(SELECT StartDate FROM 
( SELECT DATEADD(SS,-1,StartDate) AS EndDate, DATEADD(SS,1,EndDate) AS StartDate FROM #Dates ) StartMain
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #Dates A WHERE StartMain.StartDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate )) AS StartFrom,
(SELECT  EndDate FROM 
( SELECT DATEADD(SS,-1,StartDate) AS EndDate, DATEADD(SS,1,EndDate) AS StartDate FROM #Dates ) B
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #Dates A WHERE B.EndDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate ) )  AS B
WHERE StartFrom.StartDate < B.EndDate
```

The Above query will work for the question asked, and the additional thing about grouping for Single entity.

```
CREATE TABLE #DATES( ID INT,  StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (1, '2014-09-01 00:00:00.000','2015-09-02 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (1, '2014-01-16 00:00:00.000','2014-04-04 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (1, '2012-09-04 00:00:00.000','2014-01-15 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (1, '2011-09-05 00:00:00.000','2012-09-03 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (1, '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000','2015-12-31 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (2, '2014-09-01 00:00:00.000','2015-09-02 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (2, '2014-01-16 00:00:00.000','2014-04-04 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (2, '2012-09-04 00:00:00.000','2014-01-15 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (2, '2011-09-05 00:00:00.000','2012-09-03 23:59:59.000' )
INSERT INTO #DATES VALUES (2, '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000','2015-12-31 23:59:59.000' )

SELECT Main.ID, StartFrom.StartDate, EndTo.EndDate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #DATES ) Main
JOIN (SELECT StartDate, ID FROM 
     ( SELECT DATEADD(SS,-1,StartDate) AS EndDate, DATEADD(SS,1,EndDate) AS StartDate, ID FROM #Dates ) StartMain
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #Dates A WHERE StartMain.ID = A.ID AND StartMain.StartDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate )) AS StartFrom
ON Main.ID = StartFrom.ID
JOIN (SELECT  EndDate, ID FROM 
     ( SELECT DATEADD(SS,-1,StartDate) AS EndDate, DATEADD(SS,1,EndDate) AS StartDate, ID FROM #Dates ) EndMain
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #Dates A WHERE EndMain.ID = A.ID AND EndMain.EndDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate ) )  AS EndTo
ON Main.ID = EndTo.ID
WHERE StartFrom.StartDate < EndTo.EndDate
```

Hope it helps. If someone got better and optimised solution please post it on here.